# Phonegap Javascript .html() not working in iOS simulator?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ios-simulator

I'm currently having some issues with Phonegap and my HTML and Javascript codes.

HEAD SCRIPT CODES:

```
<script>
  var requestsHTML = "<li id="+displayReqId+" class='table-view-cell'>" +
      "<a class='navigate-right' href="+goToUrl+" data-transition='slide-in'>" +
        "<strong class='requestTitle'> "+displayEduLevel+"</strong>" +
        "<div class='displaySubject status'>"+displaySubject.join(", ")+"</div>" +
      "</a>" +
    "</li>";

  $("#viewRequestList").html(requestsHTML);
</script>
```

HTML BODY CODES:

```
<div class="content">

  <div class="ribbonTitle_request">    
               <img src="imgs/ribbon.png" height="80%" width="80%">     
            <div class="containerRibbon">   
               <div class="subTitle" align="center"> Pending Requests </div>   
             </div>    
  </div> 


  <div id="viewRequest" class="viewRequest card">

    <ul id="viewRequestList" class="table-view">

    </ul>

  </div>


</div>
```

As you can see, when the document runs, I want the li tag to be inserted into the body. However, nothing appears when I run it on the iOS Simulator.

How it currently looks like: http://imgur.com/9fwqlci

But when I do add the li directly into the body, it works: http://imgur.com/Mb25T7u

Would appreciate it if someone could help me with this problem. Thank you.

EDIT: Fixed codes & edited Title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<head>` the `#viewRequestList ul` isn't created yet, so `$("#viewRequestList")` won't find it. Add your script at the end of your `<body>` or into the [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.